# WP No slug when adding a pending post

Tags: wordpress, slug

I'm using the following snippet of code to add a post:

```
$post_args = array(
    'post_content'   => 'test test',
    'post_name'      => 'slughere',
    'post_title'     => 'title',
    'post_status'    => 'pending',
    'ping_status'    => 'closed',
    'comment_status' => 'closed'
);

$new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_args );
```

If I add a post with a 'publish' status, it works. But when I post it as a 'pending' post, for some reason the slug is not being added. It just stays empty.

Does anybody have any idea how this is possible of why this is happening?

Running the latest WP and even updated the core again to be sure there is nothing weird going on there.

Comment: Same problem over here. I need to set the slug BEFORE post is published. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Hi Jeurgen, it has been too long ago for me to remember what project this was on. Based on what I would do now, would be to publish the post, get the slug and after getting the slug, change the post status to pending. User will never see the actual post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the parameter **`post_name`** manually make sure to [sanitize](http://codex.wordpress.org/Data_Validation#Slugs) and assure [uniqueness](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_unique_post_slug),

So try following code:-

```
$post_args = array(
        'post_content'   => 'test test',
        'post_name'   => wp_unique_post_slug( sanitize_title( 'slughere' ) ),
        'post_title'     => 'title',
        'post_status'    => 'pending',
        'ping_status'    => 'closed',
        'comment_status' => 'closed'
);

$new_post_id = wp_insert_post( $post_args );
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Hi Akshay, thanks for the suggestion. But I'm checking if the slug is unique or not before I insert the post. Cause when it already exists it will be double content (its part of an import module). Added the sanitize_title as its a good suggestion. But did not solve my problem yet with the empty slug when I insert it as pending.